# Accesing the pixel value dor selected ROA in openCV

Tags: image, image-processing, opencv

I am working on Image Inpaiting on video project and i am selecting the portion of the image on a screen(ROI) as a rectangle and i am inpaiting that portion of the image. Now i want to save five previous frame from live video(that i can do it) and save the pixels value of that ROI of five frame/image on five different array. I will use that array to generate the background and remove the foreground object.

Any one know how i can save pixel value in array for that selected area?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

C++ interface of opencv use cv::Mat for storing image pixel.
The following code shows you how to declare a matrix B "pointing" to a ROI of matrix A.
Matrices are images. ROI is a rectangle (x=0;t=0;width=0;height=100). Use opencv highgui function to save your image.

```
cv::Mat A(640,480,CV_8C3);
cv::Rect rect(0,0,100,100);
cv::Mat B = A(rect);
cv::imwrite("my_roi.pbg",B);
```

If you need to read frames from a video, use `cv::VideoCapture cap` and `cap >> frame` to grab and retrieve each images as `cv::Mat`. If you want to go to different position in your video file use `cv::VideoCapture::set(..,CV_FRAME_MSEC)` , read [manual](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/highgui_reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html?highlight=videocapture#VideoCapture%3a%3aset).